# Git: How to clear empty directories in .git/refs/heads?

Tags: git

I've created a new `feature/cool-stuff` branch. Git created the `.git/refs/heads/feature/cool-stuff` file as expected.

Now, I deleted the `feature/cool-stuff` branch. Git deleted the  `.git/refs/heads/feature/cool-stuff` file as expected.

But, the `.git/refs/heads/feature` directory is still there (it's empty).

I guess I could delete this directory manually, but I wonder if there is a Git cleanup command that would do that for me?

Comment: I don't know of such a command. Is there any observable effect due to the presence of the `feature` subdirectory? (Other than the existence of the directory itself, that is.)

Comment: Yes, if now I create a `Feature/new-feature` branch (note the capital F), Git will create it with lowercase F: `feature/new-feature` (this is because the `feature` directory already exists).

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you are using a system with a non-case-sensitive filesystem (Windows or Mac OS X). Interesting, but I don't know of a way to avoid that without removing the empty directory first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find .git/refs -empty -type d -delete
```